# Is there a type of sensor that could measure how many times something has been scanned?

Tags: sensor, rfid

I'm doing a high school assignment for a project and I wanted to measure how many people are on a bus at a given time by scanning a bus card onto the reader, which hopefully there would be something that could measure how many times the reader is used. Is there some sort of sensor that could do this? Or is there some sort of technology that could count this sort of thing?

(I do not know anything about electrical engineering so sorry if this question was dumb!! And also I didn't know what tags to put!!)

Comment: why can't you get the info from the program that runs the scanner?

Comment: I wasn't really sure where to get information on this as the scanner is for Oyster cards and I couldn't really find anything technical from the TfL.

Comment: Do you want it to recognize the card so that duplicate scans are rejected and positive scans and negative scans indicated while counting.   A smart phone app that can recognize the ID on the card would be easiest , but still needs to be modified. Consider : 1) detection accuracy: 2) detection feedback, count start and stop inputs,manual correction.

Comment: the info could be available online ... talk to the bus company ... if you use a second scanner, then you have no guarantee that the count on one scanner would match the count on the second scanner

Comment: I'm guessing you scan your Oyster card when you get on the bus - but do you also scan it when you get off? If not then your card counter value will only ever get bigger - you'd end up with 1000's of people "still on the bus" at the end of the day ...

Comment: The best way would be to somehow modify the scanner so it can produce a count for you. Otherwise does the scanner make some kind of noise when it scans a bus card? Could you somehow detect the noise it makes?

Comment: When people exit the bus, do they scan again on the way out? Because it seems like there might be a problem with you plan. When people get on the bus they scan. So you can count riders. But when they get off the bus, how do you subtract? It seems like your count will just go up and up and never down. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi everyone! Thanks for the answers. 

I can't contact the TfL as I can't find any way to actually talk to the Engineering team which is a shame as it would give me a more in-depth insight on how the technology actually works as I really have struggled to find anything in-depth about the way the readers work online in the past week.

Comment: The plan was to display this information on an app, so I was hoping that it would be plausible to say that once scanned again on the exiting reader, the tag from the card could be removed from the database? Again, I'm not sure if this is possible or not but I don't actually have to make this as it's just hypothetical.

Comment: As for using the sound from the reader, this is also a good idea. The scanner makes 2 sounds (one for a successful scan and one for an unsuccessful scan). Would it be possible to use an audio sensor that can detect the frequency of the successful scan's sound and log how many of these successful scans are made rather than using the tags of the Oysters themselves?

Comment: You would have to analyse the sound. But I think a microphone plus some kind of computer could do it. (Maybe even an app on a mobile phone that uses the built-in microphone). Probably for a reliable system it will be more complicated than just recognizing a single frequency. First step would be to get some recordings of the sound and look at them in the time and frequency domains to see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called an RFID tag and reader.  You can get the components at Sparkfun, and they have a tutorial:

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/simultaneous-rfid-tag-reader-hookup-guide/all

This one is simpler:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15209

Comment: Thanks for the reply! By any chance, would you know anything about contactless payments on the bus systems and how this is read by a reader?